# Task.FromException c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Создаю асинхронную задачу Task.

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            BotManager manager = new BotManager(TakeBrowserFromPool());
            AccountModel accountModel = new AccountModel();
            accountModel.FillRandomData();
            manager.Registration(accountModel);
        }).ContinueWith(t => taskFinished(t));
```

Потом в ней вызываю Task.FromException

```
public Task Test(AccountModel account)
    {
        try
        {
            SignUp signUp = new SignUp(browser, account);
            signUp.Register();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        catch(TestException exception)
        {
            return Task.FromException(exception);
        }
    }
```

Вот так я ее ловлю

```
private void taskFinished(Task task)
    {
      //Тут task.Exception = null
    }
```

Проблема заключается в том что Task.Exception всегда равняется нулю.

Comment: Ошибки тут и нет. Потому что ту таску, которые вы создаёте при помощи StartNew и не возвращает никаких исключений. И вообще, где в первой таске этот метод Test? Вы же понимаете, что слово Task в начале метода - это не магическое слово, чтобы заработал асинхрон, метод действительно возвращает экземпляр класса Task. И в этом экземпляре исключение и остаётся. Так что, если вы где-то внутри одного из методов первой таски вызываете эту, то там результат и остаётся.

Comment: для проверки можете добавить в таске `throw new Exception;`